# Java MVC-pattern with Observer/Observable

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

Greetings,

I have a problem in my application I'm building in.
To give the scenario I'm in.
I have these two controllers both inherit the same model initialize from a main controller.
All controllers have their on views but I have only one model.

To problem is that. When ever changes happens to that model.
How can I notify the other controller (from the two controllers) that an update occurred?
I'm a going to use Observer/Observable or PropertyChangeEvent? And how, I'm a little bit of confused on implement both on the MVC archictecture.

Your response is highly appreciated on this matter.

Thanks,
Cyril H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar case where I used PropertyChangeSupport in order to listen to model's changes. I believe that the best way is to create an AbstractEntity that contains a private **PropertyChangeSupport** and two public methods ***addPropertyListener, removePropertyListener*** and a protected method ***firePropertyChange***. Those methods will be used as wrappers of the PropertyChangeSupport's ones. So your controllers should just addPropertyListeners in order to listen to changes of the common model.

Note:

- You should use the same instance of model accross all the controlers.
- The classes that you need are the following:

java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport

java.beans.PropertyChangeListener

Example code for how the

```
public void setValue(String value){
      String oldValue=getValue();
      this.value=value;
      firePropertyChange("value",oldValue,getValue()); 
}
```

Comment: I still confused on how to code this. Can you supply me with some tutorials that you may prefer to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your controlers should just listen to the model. (PropertyChange or something else). Why would you like your controlers to notify themselves ?

If it is the main controller you want to notify it should just listen the model too. Isn't it itself who initialize the model ?

Comment: Ahhmm... I may twisted the MVC design on my application. Isn't the model/entity only contains the getter and setters of the fields, the view contains the layout and swing objects, and controller is responsible for converting human i/o to specific application function. Did I missed something to understand what problem I am on?

Comment: @Cyril Horad: two answers are agreeing here... You must make your model observable.  This doesn't mean your view is forced to listen to the model: you can have an extra level of indirection here.  Note that there are **MANY** different types of MVC (type 1, type 2, HMVC, etc.).  A *lot* of different scenario are possible but, in any case, your model here has to be observable.

Comment: Speaking of indirection? Are you pertaining on how the changes will trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem,

- make your model `observable`, and
- your controller/s observer

Or introduce a `listener`, if former doesn't sound good to you.

Comment: I am having a problem with regards to that. My controller is inherits its view. How could I add the observer to the controoler?

Comment: @Cyril: Don't add observer to the controller, in fact make your controller an observer, by doing something similar to this, `public class MyController implements MyObserver`. BTW, `Controller` should never inherit `View`. That's not MVC -- may be somewhere else, but not on earth.

Comment: What then is right? Making the view an object of the controller? I'm little bit of confused...

Comment: @Cyril: Yes, you can define your view an instance variable in your controller. In case, you are working on web application and your view is a JSP page, then you don't need to do that, just use the URI to forward things to the view.

Comment: Actually, I'm working on JavaSE. Question, can my view only contain the layout of a partial frame of the application then the controller will be the one to handle user interaction? Is like the controllers contains the model/entity, services, etc.

Comment: @Cyril: User interaction would be handled by View, may be using event handlers. And if you are using Swing, your view itself can be an Observer, I believe.

Comment: I just still don't get it. What would be the purpose of the controller then?

Comment: @Cyril: Which view to present.

Comment: Ok. Now I have a problem with regards the Observer implementation. I can't get the model to update on the main controller in which the changes happened to another controller instanced on the main controller.